# DataGridVIew C# Заполнить столбец суммой предыдущих ячеек - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Я пытаюсь записать в 4 столбец сумму 2-х предыдущих ячеек

(данные импортировал из Access)

[image: таблица]

Код не работает 
 выдает ошибку:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidCastException"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {                   
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = (double)dataGridView1[i, 1].Value + (double)dataGridView1[i, 2].Value;     
    }
}
```

я уже все типы данных перепробовал

Comment: Нужно сделать приведение к тому типу, который в этих столбцах: `(int)dataGridView1[i, 2].Value`. Вместо `int` подставьте нужный тип.

Comment: например вот так ? 

`dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = 
(double)dataGridView1[i, 1].Value + (double)dataGridView1[i, 2].Value;`

Comment: Покажите, какая ошибка выдается

Comment: Теперь покажите, как данные попадают в `DataGridView`.

Comment: данные импортирую из Acces

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться методом

```
Double.TryParse()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы изначально пытаетесь сложить разные строки одного столбца:

```
dataGridView1[i, 1].Value + dataGridView1[i, 2].Value
```

так как при таком обращении к данным `dataGridView` изначально идет индекс столбца, а потом строки:

```
dataGridView[int columnIndex, int rowIndex]
```

Вы можете использовать `Double.TryParse()`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        double result1;
        double result2;                
        Double.TryParse(dataGridView1[1, i].Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result1);
        Double.TryParse(dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result2);
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = result1 + result2;                
    }
}
```

Также можно использовать `Convert.ToDouble()`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = 
            Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[1, i].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
            + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[2, i].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);                            
    }
}
```

Comment: при первом примере выдает ошибку 
Необработанное исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException"